# How to calculate values for my variable DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, resistors, voltage-regulator, dc, variable

I am making a variable DC power supply via Multisim and the values are given to me is V1=7, V2=15, Imax(load)=209mA (both V1 and V2 is DC value which is on U1.)

I am using resistors, an LM317 voltage regulator, and a variable resistor to change my voltage to my V1 to V2 and 2 capacitors.

The issue I am facing that I am not able to get calculate correct values for me to work for resistors, capacitors and Imax(load). but This what I have done fo far:

- VPeak=Vrms*sqrt(2)
- CS=5*Io(maybe I max)/Vp*100
- R1=250 as a constant
- R2=R1*(Vout-1.25)/1.25
- CF=1uF Tant capacitor as a constant
  I tried to apply ohms law to get desired Imax(load)=209mA on RL, but my DC value decreases and it does not even reach to the required mA, (I applied ohms law when my variable resistor is at 100%).
  [image]

This is the circuit I have drawn so far in Multisim, feel free to improve it and tell me what I have done wrong.

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i-NSvtno15pmKutNENA5YVsf4ckoWuCC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is not a workable regulator schematic with a resistance in the zener shunt path.  Zener diode shunt regulators *without* the potentiometer are theoretically possible but generally not advisable today.  At the least use a a linear regulator IC.

Comment: This circuit will not regulate well at all, and your question needs a *lot* of work.  Where is V2 on the schematic?  V1 is shown as 240 Vac, not 7(?).  What is the desired output voltage range?  What are the max and min output currents?

Comment: @AnalogKid 240 is my Vrms, The V1= 7V is DC V which is U1; also if you don't mind can you clarify, I am taking Analogue circuit this semester and I am not that well versed and how should I improve it

Comment: Where are V1 and V2? You state V1 = 7V and V2 = 15V, but V1 in your schematic is 240V AC (mains input I guess). What is the output that you want to achieve? consider using a series transistor to do the regulation, using a shunt method for any significant current will be very inefficient. Try an NPN transistor, collector to C1+, emitter to output. Resistor from C1+ to the NPN base, vener of a voltage a little higher then you need going from NPN base to ground.

Comment: @user1582568 240 is my Vrms, The V1= 7V is DC V which is U1; also if you don't mind can you clarify, I am taking Analogue circuit this semester and I am not that well versed and how should I improve it

Comment: _"the issue I am facing that I am not able to get calculate correct values for me to work for resistors and capacitor"_ - what formulas did you use?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I used VPeak=Vrms*sqrt(2), CS=5*Io(maybe I max)/Vp*100, R1=250 as a constant, R2=R1*(Vout-1.25)/1.25, CF=1uF Tant capacitor, now I am having an issue to calculate the Imax(load) on RL want it to be on Imax=209mA

Comment: _" now I am having an issue to calculate the Imax(load) on RL want it to be on Imax=209mA"_ - Surely you know Ohm's law? You have the voltage and the desired current, so...

Comment: @BruceAbbott I did apply ohms law with the with voltage and desire current but my DC value decreases and I don't even get required mA, (I applied ohms law when my variable resistor is at 100%)

Comment: Your simulation says 14.85V at 105mA (RL = 141.34 Ohms). What does the voltage decrease to with RL = 71.8 Ohms?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Honestly, I don't know I can upload my simulation to check, maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Your capacitor Cs is too small, try increasing it to 2200uF and see what happens

Comment: @S.s. I did it doesn't have that big of an impact